What's the difference between Affable and Approachable?
According to the dictionary, both words have almost identical meanings:

Approachable: Friendly and easy to talk to; easy to understand.


Affable: Pleasant, friendly, and easy to talk to.

However, my intuition suggests that the phrase "easy to talk to" carries different nuances in each definition.
For approachable, "easy to talk to" implies that you are accessible and not preoccupied, making it easy for others to approach you.
For affable, "easy to talk to" means that you are friendly and create a comforting atmosphere, making conversations pleasant and reassuring.
In other words one can be an affable person but inapproachable, and conversely.

I think you have pretty much answered your question already.

I would add that an 'authority figure' who is approachable is not intimidating or 'standing on their dignity'.

Are you looking to apply this to a particular sort of person, like a professor/teacher, parent, or friend?

I think the key to the difference is the root word "approach". Affable describes their demeanor when you talk to them, approachable refers to the fact that you're free to contact them.

M-W for affable puts more emphasis on their ease in talking to you than vice versa. When in doubt, check multiple dictionaries.
